# can any recursive looping happen from overwriting __dir__ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose, I have a custom class that does not inherit from another class (which is typically hard to inherit from), but builds a wrapper along with a few other functions that modify the behavior of the second class.

```
class TestClass:
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.data = OrigClass(*args, **kwargs)

   def __getitem__(self, key):
       ...
       x = self.data.__getitem__(key)
       ...

   def __setitem__(self, key, value):
       ...
       self.data.__setitem__(key, value)
       ...

   @staticmethod
   def _try_attr(var, item):
       if hasattr(var, item):
           return var.__getattribute__(item)
       else:
           return None


   def __getattr__(self, item):
       return TestClass._try_attr(self._data, item)


   def __repr__(self):
       ...

   def __str__(self):
       ...
```

As such, the `TestClass` is working fine with the new modifications, and falling back on `OrigClass` for methods using `__getattr__` for methods that were not re-implemented. However, in interactive mode (e.g. PyCharm's Python console) or otherwise, when I try to see `__dir__()`, the `__dir__()` in `TestClass` doesn't display / show all the attributes in `OrigClass` that are also accessible in `TestClass`.

I can try to create a new `__dir__` function within `TestClass` to merge the current `TestClass`'s `__dir__` with the `__dir__` in `OrigClass` to create `__dir__` (I'm using Python 3.x). There seems to some posts on this on SO (although not sure some of them are valid for Python 3.x).

1. However, I am worried about the common functions in `OrigClass` and `TestClass`, i.e. if there are functions like `__setitem__`, `__getitem__` in both `OrigClass` and `TestClass`, which ones will the new `__dir__` refer to?
2. Are there any other functions (e.g. some `__` functions such as `__getitem__`, `__setattr__` etc.) that refer to `__dir__`? Or, in other words, any chance of falling into a recursive loop if I overwrite `__dir__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `__dir__` returns a list of *unique strings*; it'll include the strings `'__setitem__'` and `'__getitem__'` without any reference to a specific implementation.

   In other words, it *doesn't matter* if they refer to the `TestClass` or `OrigClass` implementation. Accessing an attribute by that name on `TestClass` will find the `TestClass` implementation.
2. `__dir__` is purely informative and only used by the `dir()` command. Other tools (such as the Python `help()` system) may rely on `dir()`.

   You'll not get into a recursive loop, the method is entirely optional, there is no base implementation as `dir()` otherwise collects information about an object by other means.

You can use `dir()` on the `self.data` attribute, and append to the resulting list to create the `TestClass` version:

```
def __dir__(self):
    base = dir(self.data)
    base.extend(('_try_attr', 'data'))
    return base
```

The resulting list of strings will be sorted again by `dir()`.

Comment: Not a problem.  Happy to help a ninja any time.